# Ajax link which can also be opened in new tab? (like Facebook)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

If I simply click on most of Facebook link it will be loaded on same page using ajax but if I middle/ctrl-click it will be loaded in new tab.

I have done it half way but it does not work completely, [Edit] middle-click and right-click>open-in-new-tab opens is new tab but ctrl-click calls onclick[/Edit]. Any idea how to do it correctly?

```
<a href="/link/location" onclick="doAjax(); return false;">link</a>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" for ctrl-click? What actually happens?

Comment: @nnnnnn `doAjax();` runs instead of opening in new tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of always returning false directly in the (inline) onclick, you want to return the result of the function, and then in the function test whether the control key was used:

```
<a href="/link/location" onclick="return doAjax(event);">link</a>

<script>
function doAjax(e) {
    if (!e) e = window.event;

    if (!e.ctrlKey) {
        alert("Ajax code here");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DrvYg/

More information about the properties of the event object for mouse events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/MouseEvent

(By the way, you shouldn't need the `if (!e)` bit for an inline event handler, but I'm kind of used to writing it because I don't tend to use inline event handlers.)

Comment: thanks for response, i was also thinking about it before asking, but the problem is that i'm not sure if ctrl always means open-in-new-tab in every environment. For example if use has customized it's environment, etc.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about that. The above allows whatever the default is for control-click to go ahead, which means the worst case for you is the link will open in the current window/tab, replacing the current page. Given that you are linking to one of your own pages anyway, I don't think that's a problem. Also, note that that is what will happen for users who have JavaScript turned off, which you should allow for anyway. Just make sure the `href` is appropriate to give a non-Ajax version of your functionality.

Comment: great... i added `if (!e.ctrlKey && !e.button == 1) {` to include middle mouse click but in IE the middle button is 4 not 1, am i wrong?