# href link calls ajax with left button and opens in new tab with middle button - not working in FF

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox

I have a link that makes an ajax call on left click, but opens in a new tab when ctrl+click or middle click.

I copied the code from here, [Ajax link which can also be opened in new tab? (like Facebook)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651091/ajax-link-which-can-also-be-opened-in-new-tab-like-facebook/8651177#8651177)

But its not working in my firefox. The problem is that it never triggers the ajax call, it always opens the link instead.

Here is the html code:

```
<a href="http://forma.culturadigital.cc/es/casos" onclick="javascript:unhide('casos', 'nil', 'nil');javascript:activate('menucasos');javascript:return makeGetRequest(event,'http://forma.culturadigital.cc/pages/casos.php');" class="menu_link"><span id="menucasos" class="nonactive">&nbsp;Casos de estudio&nbsp;</span></a>
```

And this is the ajax code:

```
function makeGetRequest(e, key) {
if (!e) e = window.event;

if (!e.ctrlKey && !e.button == 1) { //this is to be able to open links by clicking the wheel button or ctrl+click
    http.open('GET', key, true);
    //assign a handler for the response
    http.onreadystatechange = processResponse;
    //actually send the request to the server
    http.send(null);

    return false; //this is important, otherwise the href link will trigger and not the onclick 
    }
}
```

It works fine in Chrome and IE. But not in FF. The actual website is [FORMA](http://forma.culturadigital.cc)

Comment: Remove all the `javascript:` parts in the onclick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `javascript:` parts in the `onclick`.

```
<a href="http://forma.culturadigital.cc/es/casos" onclick="unhide('casos', 'nil', 'nil');activate('menucasos');return makeGetRequest(event,'http://forma.culturadigital.cc/pages/casos.php');" class="menu_link"><span id="menucasos" class="nonactive">&nbsp;Casos de estudio&nbsp;</span></a>
```

Prefixing with `javascript:` is for the `href` attribute in a link, in the `onclick` handler you should place normal javascript.

Other than that there is an error in your js, in the `activate` function.

it starts with:

```
function activate(fieldID){
    var e = window.event;

    if (!e.ctrlKey && !e.button == 1) {
```

`window.event` returns `undefined` for firefox. change it to pass the event as a parameter like you do in `makeGetRequest`

```
activate(event,'menucasos');
```

and

```
function activate(e, fieldID){
    if (!e.ctrlKey && !e.button == 1) {
```

Comment: @fartagaintuxedo do you get an error in the console?

Comment: U are right, it was the activate function that was wrong. I didnt get the error in the js console for some reason...